# How do I differentiate between, xterm and firefox, if both call syscall=socketcall(recvmsg)

Tags: linux, security, linux-audit

---- type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(Sunday 03
September 2017 ^E.370:2020074) : proctitle=/usr/bin/xterm -fg white -bg
black type=SOCKETCALL msg=audit(Sunday 03 September 2017 ^E.370:2020074)
: nargs=3 a0=0x3 a1=0xbf9a8274 a2=0x0 type=SYSCALL msg=audit(Sunday 03
September 2017 ^E.370:2020074) : arch=i386 **syscall=socketcall(recvmsg)**
success=no exit=EAGAIN(Resource temporarily unavailable) **a0=recvmsg
a1=0xbf9a81f4 a2=0x0 a3=0x0** items=0 ppid=16776 pid=16777 auid=unset
uid=root gid=root euid=root suid=root fsuid=root egid=root sgid=root
fsgid=root tty=(none) ses=unset **comm=xterm exe=/usr/bin/xterm**
key=jackass

---- type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(Sunday 03 September 2017
^E.638:2020105) : proctitle=/usr/local/firefox/firefox type=SOCKETCALL
msg=audit(Sunday 03 September 2017 ^E.638:2020105) : nargs=3 a0=0x4
a1=0xbfaf8854 a2=0x0 type=SYSCALL msg=audit(Sunday 03 September 2017
^E.638:2020105) : arch=i386 **syscall=socketcall(recvmsg)** success=no
exit=EAGAIN(Resource temporarily unavailable) **a0=recvmsg a1=0xbfaf87d4
a2=0x0 a3=0xb771f000** items=0 ppid=22804 pid=22815 auid=unset uid=geek
gid=geek euid=geek suid=geek fsuid=geek egid=geek sgid=geek fsgid=geek
tty=(none) ses=unset comm=firefox **exe=/usr/local/firefox/firefox**
key=jackass

I am using:

> auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=i686 -S socketcall -k jackass

I found this helpful but it doesn't seem to work in the above example.
[Suse Audit Docs](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled10/audit_sp1/data/sec_audit_scenipc.html) Example *-F a0=1*

can filter but since both calls use *recvmsg* this is not useful. I need some way to differentiate using **a1 a2 a3**. The SUSE docs say:

> -F a1=10 filter narrows the matches down to socket system calls carrying the IPv6 protocol family domain parameter (PF_INET6).

However in these calls a1=0xb5d12130 which is unreadable mumbo-jumbo. It looks to be a pointer to an array of parameters for the corresponding call. [Multiplexed System Calls on x86](http://jkukunas.blogspot.in/2010/05/x86-linux-networking-system-calls.html)

> int socketcall(int call, unsigned long *args);

```
args points to a block containing the actual arguments, which are passed
       through to the appropriate call.
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [recvfrom(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvfrom.2.html) man page.

That system call takes a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), and in different processes that fd would probably be different (and refer to some different inode).

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (freely downloadable).

You might also use `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)). Probably `ls -l /proc/$(pidof firefox)/fd/`  and `ls -l /proc/$(pidof xterm)/fd/`  tells different things for these file descriptors.